# MySQL: Is it possible to update two fields in one table by referencing another table by a different key?

Tags: mysql

[image: MySQL Referencing Another Table]

I want to have my `user_comments` table dynamically update its `show_name` and `location_name` fields when a record is queried from that table. The `location_id` is not unique in the `user_comments` table, but `id` is unique in the `locations` table.

I don't want to populate the table. I just want the fields to be filled on a query.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Why on earth do you have your ID field a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: @Siyul should it be a char(6)? It is a unique, but not consecutive, six letter word such as AXDCFV.

Comment: @JNevill this answer seems to show how to copy the information once, right? Not dynamically every time `user_comments` is queried. Or am I wrong 'bout that?

Comment: That's true. I didn't understand that requirement. You'll need a trigger to do what you want then, I believe.

Answer (score -1):

A **mysql trigger** may help you

Reference Link http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx

You can also do it manually with your code. When updating location table, you can run the query to update the comments table as well referencing the same **id**